# C++: Member Overloading Binary Operators which Modify the Left Operand eg +=

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm learning about Operator Overloading at the moment on learncpp.com and came across a statement that I can't quite wrap my head around. Here it is:

> When dealing with binary operators that do modify the left operand
> (e.g. operator+=), the member function version is typically preferred.
> **In these cases, the leftmost operand will always be a class type**, and having the object being modified become the one pointed to by
> *this is natural. Because the rightmost operand becomes an explicit parameter, there’s no confusion over who is getting modified and who
> is getting evaluated.

I don't understand why the left hand operand will always be a class type. If I were overloading +=, for example, why couldn't I overload with the user defined class as the righthand parameter, like below?

```
void operator+=(int blah, MyNewClass foo);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't ignore the words "typically preferred" and "these cases". You *can* do what you suggest, but such an operator won't earn you any respect from your coworkers. (It might get you a few points in an "obfuscated C++" contest, though.)

Comment: @molbdnilo, what I'm struggling to understand is the assertion that the leftmost operand will always be a class type. Whilst my example might be uncommon (or ill-advised), I don't see why it would be impossible. Do you think you could elaborate on why it is impossible?

Comment: It will always be a class type **in these cases**, and those cases are *the member function version*. And as I said, it *is* possible. Did you even try?

Comment: Ah I see - 'these cases' refers to when the operator is being overloaded with a member function, not binary operators that modify the left operand. That makes complete sense - thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Despite the comments, you read this **correctly**: it’s talking about all such modifying operators, and it’s *using* the statement about the left-hand operand to justify the idea of a member function being “typically preferred”.  (If it’s going to be a class-type object, you definitely have the opportunity to use a member function, and we generally prefer to express modifications to such objects in terms of member functions.)

The passage simply doesn’t consider the **esoteric** possibilities of overloading with non-member functions:

```
enum nil {};
// Use left-to-right compound assignment:
void operator+=(const int &i,nil &n)
{n=static_cast<nil>(n+i);}
// Make something into a pointer (*):
template<class T>
void* operator*=(T &t,nil) {return &t;}

struct A {operator int();};
// Convert sum to a percentage (%):
double operator%=(A a,A b) {return (a+b)/100.;}
// Infix call notation (like $ in Haskell):
template<class R>
R operator&=(R f(int),A a) {return f(a);}
```

Very occasionally someone might find a clever way of using, say, `>>=` in this fashion to emulate Haskell, but for someone just **learning** the language (to whom that passage is certainly addressed), perhaps the very possibility of such examples is best left unsaid.  (Forget I said anything.)